# Multiple integer values in JSON are adding automatically

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a beginner at Javascript and something strange is happening with my JSON which I don't quite understand. I'm working with a dummy object which looks like this:

```
var data2 = {
    incoming:12,
    outgoing:15,
    misc:3
};
```

Now, when I create a variable like this:

```
 var total = data2.incoming += data2.outgoing += data2.misc;
```

And call it up in the console log, I get the correct answer of 30. But when I call the individual values in console log, they seem to automatically add together so that data2.incoming gives me 30, data2.outgoing gives me 18, and data2.misc gives me 3. Clearly the value for incoming is including all the other integer values, and outgoing is including also the incoming integer value.

Can someone help me to understand why this is? I've moved the variables around to be global/local and that made no difference. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: x+=y is the same as x=x+y so you add each to the previous var in your code

Comment: Thanks, silly of me to miss that!

Answer (score 2):

You want to add three integers to get a total. This will do just that:

```
var total = data2.incoming + data2.outgoing + data2.misc;
```

The expression you have does more:

1. it first adds 3 and 15 and stores 18 in `data2.outgoing`,
2. then it adds 12 and 18 and stores the result (30) in `data2.incoming`,
3. finally, it assigns 30 to total.